# How does the "intervals()" function from {nlme} in R perform inference on variance components?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

The help page doesn't specify which method this function is using.

If I understand correctly, lme4 uses bootstrap to get the CIs, but I don't think the "intervals()" function from {nlme} uses Bootstrap.

Could anyone provide a reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The methods for the `intervals()` generic of models fitted in **nlme** calculate Wald-type confidence intervals for the model parameters. For the variance-covariance components, the *natural* parameterization is used, namely, confidence intervals are calculated for the logarithms of standard deviations, and the logits (i.e., $\log\{\rho / (1 - \rho)\}$) of correlations. However, note that these intervals will not jointly satisfy the positive-definiteness constraint.

Comment: I see. Can I ask a follow-up question? How does it obtain the standard error for variance components?